# Get photo uri android 2.3.7 and android 4

Tags: android, photo

i'm having some trouble about gettin photo uri between android 2.x and 4.x

The following code works perfectly on 2.x but not for 4.x

```
 public static Uri getPhotoURIFromAddress(Context activity, String address) {
            String contactId = fetchContactIdFromPhoneNumber(address,activity);
            //Se non trovo il contatto il rubrica
            if(contactId.equals("0")){
                    return null;
            }

            ContentResolver contentResolver = activity.getContentResolver();
            try {
                Cursor cursor = contentResolver
                        .query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                        + "="
                                        + contactId
                                        + " AND "

                                        + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                        + "='"
                                        + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                                        + "'", null, null);

                if (cursor != null) {
                    if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        Log.i("No photo","No photo");
                        return null; // no photo
                    }
                } else {

                    return null; // error in cursor process
                }
                cursor.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
```

How i can intregate working code for 4.x ?? Thanks